# awk if line contains

Tags: bash, awk

Currently using,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($3 in a)' find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

to search a directory containing multiple files, for strings from a .txt (find.txt)

find.txt contains

```
example1
example 2
example@eampol.com
exa exa exa123
...
```

example of .txt files within directory

```
example      example       example.com
example 2    example       example     lol
```

now currently it searches for the string within column 3, using ($3 in a) meaning $3 = column #3, but sometimes string can be on $1 or $5 and so on, how can I get it to search every column instead of just the 3rd?

Comment: Aren't you just trying to do `grep -f find.txt path_to_100_files/*` ?

Comment: Seems like a job for `grep` indeed.  But if you want to reference the whole line instead of `$3`, don't you just want to use `$0`?

Comment: nunuhuex ininindian okampomon

Comment: I think my comment got deleted, @PesaThe grep seems to produce false matches, like if find.txt contains just " example ", it seems output matches such as, "  
nunuhuex ininindian okampomon " now i don't know whether that contains " ex " and/or " amp " same as example, but it should be exact string not just letters from the string :S

Comment: "but sometimes string can be on $1 or $5 and so on,". hmm. to infinity? You'll have to put some boundaries on your problem. You seem to understand how column searching works in `awk`, now you just need to refine your rules to get the correct output. OR edit your Q to include sample input that covers all cases you need AND the expected output given those inputs. Good luck.

Comment: My gnu `grep` version 3.1 works fine with `-f` switch with your data without any false matches. For better results you can use `grep -Ff find.txt 100files/*`. You can even play with option `-w` of grep = word regex matching = capture entire words

Comment: This problem would certainly be easier if the `path_to_100_files/*` files contained only one filename per line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR==FNR{a[$1];next}
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in a) { print; next } }
' find.txt path_to_100_files/*
```

The above assumes your existing script behaves as desired given `exa exa exa123`.